# wordpress using switch_to_blog

Tags: php, wordpress

i am using wordpress multisite. i am creating a function that when you post on 1 site, it will post the same post on another blog if required.

i am currently using switch_to_blog(), here is my code:

```
switch_to_blog(2);

$my_post = array(
  'post_title'    => $post_title,
  'post_content'  => $post_content,
  'post_status'   => 'publish',
  'post_author'   => $post_author,
  //'post_category' => array(8,39)
);

// Insert the post into the database
wp_insert_post( $my_post );

restore_current_blog();
```

the above is ran on a save_post action. it works fine and posts to both blogs. The only issue is on the blog i switch to wp_insert_post gets stuck in a loop and have thousands of posts added!

Any reason why that would happen from the above code?

Comment: Where is this code located? Which file and which hook?

Answer (score 0):

That's because `wp_insert_post` calls the action `save_post`, hence the loop. You have to remove the action, insert the post and add the action again.

The idea on how to control the first save is from [Check for update vs new post on save_post action](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/48678/12615). Also see [Why does save_post action fire when creating a new post?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/19538/12615). I added a check for the post statuses of `auto-draft` and `inherit`.

```
<?php
/* Plugin Name: Publish to Network */

add_action( 'save_post', 'cross_publish_so_17611289', 10, 2 );

function cross_publish_so_17611289( $post_id, $post_object )
{
    if( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE )
        return;

    if( defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) && DOING_AJAX )
        return;

    # Block auto-drafts and revisions
    if( in_array( $post_object->post_status, array( 'auto-draft', 'inherit' ) ) )
        return;

    $termid = get_post_meta( $post_id, '_termid', true );

    # It's a new post
    if( empty( $termid ) )
    {
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '_termid', 'update' );
        remove_action( 'save_post', 'cross_publish_so_17611289' );
        switch_to_blog(2);
        $my_post = array(
          'post_title'    => $post_object->post_title,
          'post_content'  => $post_object->post_content,
          'post_status'   => 'publish',
          'post_author'   => $post_object->post_author,
        );
        wp_insert_post( $my_post );
        restore_current_blog();
        add_action( 'save_post', 'cross_publish_so_17611289', 10, 2 );
    }
}
```